# Swap parameters from hibernate.cfg.xml and beans.xml

Tags: xml, spring, hibernate, configuration, parameters

I've got a (maybe simple) question.
I've created a osgi bundle using Spring and Hibernate. It is very uncomfortable to edit the hibernate.cfg.xml and the beans.xml on every computer so that the service will work (e.g. ip adress for the database, ports etc.) - so I want to swap it to one properties file which can be easy edited without rebuild the complete service from source.

But i don't know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) to lay out the configuration. This allows you to specify the database configuration as system properties when you start the OSGi framework.

Comment: Thanks, you both helped me, but i can only accept one answer, so I accept mbelow's because is has less rep :-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Hibernate.cfg.xml file, you can configure everything inside of Spring Context and thus make use of Properties Configurer. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/ctapobep/hibernate-training/blob/m2.entitylifecycle/src/main/resources/org/javatalks/training/hibernate/appContext.xml) sample.